# How to use HTML code present in a string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on something where I want to use this HTML code that is present in a string variable after passing it to some other function.

```
var foo = "<html><body><div class='myClass'><div id='myId'>Hello World!!</div></div></body></html>";
```

Comment: What do you mean with using it? And where? In the browser, in nodejs or somewhere else?

Comment: do you need to extract class and id from those elements without knowing their values? as in, class could be `myClass`, `anotherClass`, and so on?

Comment: I mean I want to use this HTML code somewhere else that is getting passed through a variable

Comment: Keep in mind that this way of executing code have security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cheerio.js](https://cheerio.js.org/) in this case.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var foo = "<html><body><div class='myClass'><div id='myId'>Hello World!!</div></div></body></html>"
const $ = cheerio.load(foo);

$('div#myId').text('Hello there!');
$('div#myId').addClass('newClass');

$.html();
//=> <html><body><div class='myClass'><div id='myId'>Hello World!!</div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is something new for me. I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) to turn your string into a [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) object.

```js
const data = "<html><body><div class='myClass'><div id='myId'>Hello World!!</div></div></body></html>";

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

const myClass = doc.querySelector('.myClass');
const myId = doc.querySelector('#myId');

console.log(myClass, myId);
```

Comment: This approach looks quite simple. Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Do these steps:

1. You Need to parse string to html like this:

   ```
   let myhtml = document.createElement("html");
   myhtml.innerHTML = foo;
   ```
2. After you parsed you html you can do what you want. Like if you want to `class="myClass"` element than you can do like this:

   `const myelement1 = myhtml.querySelector(".myClass");`

   Similarly if you want `id = "myid"` element than you can do like
   this:

   `const myelement2 = myhtml.querySelector("#myid");`

Comment: Thank you for the response but I don't want to create a new html element for this.